# When will ConcurrentDictionary TryRemove return false

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency

Will it only return false if the dictionary does not contain a value for the given key or will it also return false due to thread race conditions, like another thread adds/updates something?

Question in code:

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, string> cd = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, string>();

// This might fail if another thread is adding with key value of 1.
cd.TryAdd(1, "one"); 

// Will this ever fail if no other thread ever removes with the key value of 1?
cd.TryRemove(1);
```

**Edit:**
I think that it only will return false if it does not contain a value for the given key, but want to be absolutely sure.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

While [Mitch is right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3519557/when-will-concurrentdictionary-tryremove-return-false/3519577#3519577) that a `ConcurrentDictionary` is not vulnerable to race conditions, I think the answer to the question you are asking is that yes, if the key is present, `TryRemove` will work and will return `true`.

In the code you posted, there's no way that `TryRemove` would return `false` since `cd` is a local variable not accessed anywhere else. But if some code elsewhere were given a reference to this `ConcurrentDictionary` object and were removing keys on a separate thread, then it's possible that `TryRemove` could return `false`, even here -- but **only because the key was already removed**, not because some other action is being performed on the dictionary and the key is somehow "stuck" there.

Answer (score 5):

The [ConcurrentDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287129.aspx) does not suffer from race conditions. That's why you use it.

> Return Value
>
> true if an object was removed
>   successfully; otherwise, false.

Answer (score 4):

One other point to make:

> ```
> // This might fail if another thread is adding with key value of 1.
> cd.TryAdd(1, "one");
> ```

This comment is incorrect and possibly suffers from the same misconception about what it means to 'try'. It's not about a concurrent attempt to add, it's whether a value has already been added with key `1`.

Consider a standard `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`. The equivalent code would be:

```
if (!d.Contains(1))
    d.Add(1, "one");
```

This requires two operations. There's no way to design such an API to be threadsafe, as `cd` might have a value with key `1` added between the call to `Contains` and `Add`, which would then result in `Add` throwing.

The concurrent collections have APIs that logically bundle these test-and-do pairs into single atomic operations, behind a single API.